# Changing the color of the links in my bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code for my navbar:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
   <div class="container">
       <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
           <a href="" class="navbar-brand"><img style ="max-width:100px; margin-top: -7px;" src="images/firma-Edgar-Ayales.png" alt=""></a>
       </div><!--End navbar-header-->  
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="navbar-collapse">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
               <li><a href="#portfolio">Feedback</a>
               <li><a href="#features">Gallery</a>
               <li><a href="#gallery">Features</a>
               <li><a href="#feedback">Faq</a>
               <li><a href="#contact">ContactUs</a>
           </ul>
       </div>
   </div><!-- End container -->
```

And I want to change the links color, I tried this in my css:

```
.navbar {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    font-family: "Raleway";
font-size:10pt;
letter-spacing: 3pt;
color: black;
```

}

I also tried adding !important but I can't make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your css more specific, color applied by bootstrap is on `a`. So overriding rule will be:

```
.navbar-nav > li >a{
  color:black;
}
```

to override the default rule applied by bootstrap on anchor:

```
a {
  color: #337ab7;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

**[Pen](http://codepen.io/pramodsankarl/pen/rVyvQR)**

This makes sure that this color is applied only to the anchor which is direct descendant of li which is direct descendant of `.navbar-nav`. In order to apply globally (all hyperlinks in your webpage), You could as well override by doing `a{color:black}`. You also need to make sure you are loading your css after bootstrap so that that takes the precedence over bootstrap. Avoid using `!important` it will destroy any cascadeability of the css and will prevent any overriding later on.

Comment: So, I need to make a full path to the item I want to override, thats the explanation right?

Comment: @Pablo no you really do not. But specifying a full path makes sure that this color is applied _only to the anchor_ which is direct descendant of li under nav-bar-nav. You could as well override by doing `a{color:black}` provided you are loading your css after bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
   <div class="container">
       <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
           <a href="" class="navbar-brand"><img style ="max-width:100px; margin-top: -7px;" src="images/firma-Edgar-Ayales.png" alt=""></a>
       </div><!--End navbar-header-->  
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="navbar-collapse">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="links">
               <li><a href="#portfolio">Feedback</a>
               <li><a href="#features">Gallery</a>
               <li><a href="#gallery">Features</a>
               <li><a href="#feedback">Faq</a>
               <li><a href="#contact">ContactUs</a>
           </ul>
       </div>
   </div><!-- End container -->
```

CSS:

```
#links a{
     color:#000000;
     font-size:18px;
}
```

I just added `id="links"` to the ul, and then referenced the a's in that with CSS

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution" https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/52/

CSS:

```
.nav>li>a{
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    font-family: "Raleway";
font-size:10pt;
letter-spacing: 3pt;
color: black; 
}
```